# Get access token without user login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, publishing

Using the access token provided by Facebook we were doing offline wall publishing by saving the access token in DB when the user logs into our application first. But now the access token gets expired if user change his/her password. So we are unable to get the access token unless the user logs into our application.

Please help to get valid access token to do wall publishing without the user log into our application.

Thanks
Senthil

Answer (score 2):

> Please help to get valid access token to do wall publishing without the user log into our application.

That is not possible. User interaction is *required* before you can do anything on behalf of the user.

The system is *designed* to work this way.

Comment: Is there any way to get new access token from old access token with out user log into my app.

Comment: @SenthilRajaNatarajan yes, see my answer: it includes a link to official sample code used to obtain a new access token when the old one has expired.

Comment: @CBroe: the scenario described by OP assumes that the user has _already_ granted permission to the client and thus, the question seeks to renew _expired_ tokens.

Comment: So what? You still need user interaction to get a new access token. If you wouldn’t, then deprecating offline_access wouldn’t make much sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/)'s `PHP` example code from Facebook's developer blog. it should be trivial to implement.

do however bear in mind that the `offline_access` permission is deprecated and will be [removed](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#october-2012) in October 2012.